# Regarding scrollbar in <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe

I have made a `<iframe>` code (with scrolling set to yes) in my website. When the website is viewed in a browser on computer, the scroll-bar is visible but on mobile browser(android, i didnt check in others) the scroll-bar is not visible.

I want to know if there is any way to make the mobile viewer aware that the section (which consist iframe) can be scrolled? I dont want to add a text line in my website for this purpose.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `iframe` in a div and add the following styles:

**Snippet**

```css
/* The last 2 styles are important, and the rest varies */

.scroller {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
/* The style for iframe varies */

.scroller iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <iframe src="//example.com" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>
```